# Code works in Codepen but not when called with index.html

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, issue-tracking

https://codepen.io/mdaw11/pen/rNMbdqd

Created this little issue tracker for public use, works fine in Codepen, however once I try to open it in Chrome browser, the console outputs error 
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at fetchIssues (main.js:71)
at onload ((index):10)'

This tells me that there is something wrong with my `fetchIssues();` perhaps `var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));` isn't outputting what I expect it to be?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Add the `defer` attribute to your `<script>` tag in your HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

Could be `fetchIssues()` is being executed too early and could also happen if you don't have anything saved to the localStorage yet. Also double check what `localStorage.getItem('issues')` returns.

To fix that error you could try something like:

```
var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues') || '[]');
```

Comment: hm well that fixed the error(thank you for that) but now it isnt logging any issues to the screen. `localStorage.getItem('issues') returns null` could this be the problem? Since i'm trying to iterate through the issues.length?

Comment: @Omki yes that's the issue. Check what's being saved. `localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues)); ` make sure  `JSON.stringify(issues)` returns a json string. I think that's failing. or you might be calling `getItem` before `setItem`

Comment: How do i check that `JSON.stringify(issues)` returns a json string?

Comment: You could do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(issues));` inside the function.